# Order grid columns in code

Tags: acumatica

I've created a custom screen which formats grid fields based on setup data in another table.  One thing I'm trying to do is find out if there is a way to order the field columns in a grid in code, i.e., order the columns based on a column order information I obtain from that setup table.

Is this possible?

Comment: why you need to have custom code for that? By default acumatica grid have that option where the user will be able to order the columns and save it. So in that case you just need to set a default order.

Comment: So that it can be done in a setup table which determines many things, e.g., string length, decimal precision, visibility, label, and more.  It's so that a generic screen can essentially be (sort of) customized via a setup screen.

Comment: From the lack of responses - I'm assuming this is not possible...